# Breaking lengthy line using three dots (...) gives invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> text = ('Put several strings within parentheses '
...         'to have them joined together.')
>>> text
'Put several strings within parentheses to have them joined together.'
```

The above example was copied from python official documentation. When i try that from my pc i got the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\pypgm\training\test3.py", line 2
    ...         'to have them joined together.')
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using Thonny IDE

Comment: Don't write the dots. Their something your Python shell might insert to show you're mid way through a statement, but you don't type them in. Don't type in the `>>>` prompt either.

Comment: The ellipsis (or three dots) were not supposed to be typed. They're the output of whatever interactive interpreter the author's using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those three dots are generated automatically in the interactive interpreter for aligning the input with the opening `>>>`; if you're writing regular code in an IDE, you don't want or need them.

In actual code, you'd just type:

```
text = ('Put several strings within parentheses '
        'to have them joined together.')
```

Note lack of both `>>>` and `...`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a similar way in python using the **line continuation operator** i.e. "\"

Examples:

```
# Ex.1

x = 1
s =  x + x**2/2 + x**3/3 \
       + x**4/4 + x**5/5 \
       + x**6/6 + x**7/7 \
       + x**8/8
print(s)
# 2.7178571428571425


----------


# Ex.2

text = ('Put several strings within parentheses ' \
        'to have them joined together.')
print(text)


----------


# Ex.3

x = 1
s =  x + x**2/2 \
       + x**3/3 \
       + x**4/4 \
       + x**6/6 \
       + x**8/8
print(s)
# 2.3749999999999996
```